# Rewriting the URL of a custom post to a certain page

Tags: url-rewriting

I am building a restaurant menu plugin.  The page asdf.com/menu shows a list of menu categories, which is a custom post type. I want the URL asdf.com/menu/category-name to be rewritten to a page I created with the slug of menu-category.  I have the following function in my plugin:

```
add_action('init', function(){
   add_rewrite_rule('^menu/(.*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=menu-category', 'top');
}, 1);
```

When I visit the URL asdf.com/menu/chicken-fish, nothing is rewritten. I get the "That page can not be found" error. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you flush rewrite rules after adding this? I'm not sure why you're pointing everything at a single page if these are posts in a custom post type. I also presume you want to know what menu item was requested, which your current rule doesn't do.

Comment: Am i supposed to flush the rewrite rules afterwards?  If so, where do I do this?

Comment: So I added the flush function into the activation hook.  I am not getting the "Not found" error anymore, but it still doesn't show the page that I want.  Only the single post.